# What is the most efficient way to split up raw video into rough clips using Premiere Pro?

Tags: premiere, clipping

I've got a few hours of raw video that I want to split into individual clips for later work. Being somewhat new to Premiere, I'm not too sure of the workflow for doing this.

What I've been doing so far is scrubbing through the source video and hitting the <kbd>m</kbd> key to leave a marker where I want the breaks to be (bonus: if I hit the key at the wrong time, I can just drag the markers around).

So far so good - now I want to use those markers to slice the video accordingly.

How do I do this?

Better yet, is there a better workflow for this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably better off making [subclips](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/how-to/premierepro-soft-subclips-cc.html).

Subclips are pieces of footage that have been pre-edited, and appear in the project window as a separate clip, although they reference the same footage. In newer editions of PP there is the option of creating hard and soft subclips.

NB you can use the keyboard shortcuts <kbd>i</kbd> and <kbd>o</kbd> for setting in and out points and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> for making the subclip (instead of noobishly clicking with the mouse like the guy in the tutorial). That will save your carpal tunnel.